# Spinning .png image in video sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor

i'm a total newbie to Blender ( v 2.81a ) but i'd like to spin .png images in the video sequence editor. So not rotation , but really spinning around their own axis, is there an easy way to do this ? I've been looking on the net,but can't find the solution.
Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2D scaling can create the illusion of 3D spinning.

Comment: hmm, i'm a newbie so don't really understand. 
i'm talking 2D anyway, so i'd like to rotate an image, but around its own axis,and in the  video sequence editor,  any tips ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in Blender VSE, I've added an image;

[image]

I added an adjustment layer;

[image]

Then an effect layer (transform);

[image]

(You can see each addition in the sequencer)

[image]

@batFINGER was talking about this scaling (as if a coin was spinning on a side);

[image]

I feel like you were probably asking for this;

[image]

**Thing to note:** The adjustment layer and effect layer need to overlap the image on it's layer.